# How to uninstall python 2.17.13, and keep python 3.7.6 as the default version on debian 9?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, openssh

I installed a Django package on GCP (Debian 9 OS), that comes with the following softwares:

- Django (2.2.9)
- Git (2.25.0)
- Apache (2.4.41)
- lego (3.3.0)
- MySQL (5.7.29)
- Node.js (10.18.1)
- OpenSSL (1.1.1d)
- PostgreSQL (11.6)
- Python (3.7.6)
- SQLite (3.31.0.)
- Subversion (1.13.0)

When I type the command `python -V`

I get the following python version: 2.17.13

When I type `python3 -V`

I get the following version: 3.7.6

How can I uninstall the previous version permanently and keep the current one as the default?

Here's what I tried and I didn't work:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python*
```

usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.5   /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.5m

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

Returns nothing

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

Returns nothing

Comment: the command that you use is `update-alternatives ...` or `# update-alternatives ...`?

Comment: update-alternatives ...

Comment: show `update-alternatives --list python` and `update-alternatives --config python`

Comment: It's not a good idea to uninstall default Python version. Some scripts or other default software on your OS may be depending on it and you'll break the system.

Comment: Tnx xyres for letting me now, I was gonna break everything! So, how do I go about simply making the latest version the default one as it's already pre-installed?

Comment: miszcz2137 - update-alternatives --list python returns update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python

Comment: @CodingNoob It's not a good idea to change the system default either. But you can set a default version only for a particular project by using [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). Personally, I use [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make things a bit easier. This approach allows you to have multiple Python versions or (django versions) for multiple projects.

Comment: Python3 is already installed on your system. There is nothing you need to install or change. I do not recommend trying to change anything other than to use `python3` as the program name for Python 3 programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend uninstalling python2.  Install python3 and make sure the directory where you install it is included in your systems $PATH variable.  You will need to do something like this.  Note, depending on how you install python3, some installers will automatically update your $PATH variable.

Example installing python3 in  "/Library/Frameworks/python3" directory.

Show current $PATH variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

update .bashrc in home directory (append to current $PATH)

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/python3:${PATH}"
```

reload .bashrc (or exit and start terminal back up)

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Confirm correct python install will be run when typing python3 into terminal.

```
$which python3
/Library/Frameworks/python3
```

Comment: That charmingly worked, but only partially, as the changes don't seem to take place when I check from the AWS Cloud9 IDE terminal. Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/IY1ej8q.png

Comment: A new AWS specific question may help better, but I'd start by looking here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html.

Comment: I checked today the python version via the SSH connection and it still shows Python 2.7.13